# dual citizenship under The protective umbrage of the queen

Tags: canada, brazil

I have dual Canadian /american citizenship because my mother was born and raised in /Canada. I plan to get married soon. Will my future wife be able to enjoy the perqs of a Canadian passport? I plan on retiring in Calgary and living  the rest of my days there, but I have some time yet before that happens.
    Do I have to wait until we are both residing there? AND; Will she have to relinquish her Brazilian citizenship? (she is dual American/Brazilian)
    Her parents were born and raised in Brazil...she was born in the U.S.

Answer (score 1):

[This link](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/helpcentre/answer.asp?qnum=357&top=5) is probably helpful.  To summarize:

- The spouse of a Canadian citizen has to follow exactly the same rules to become a citizen as anyone else (for example, live in Canada for long enough).  Note that this is unlike (e.g.) Germany, where the spouse of citizen can naturalize much faster than other people.
- A Canadian citizen can sponsor their spouse to become a permanent resident in Canada (which is a useful step on the way to being a citizen).

According to [this link](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/helpcentre/answer.asp?qnum=359&top=5) your wife would not have to renounce her Brazilian or US citizenship in order to become Canadian, *however* according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brazilian_nationality_law#Dual_nationality_and_loss_of_Brazilian_nationality) Brazil *would* regard her as having lost Brazilian citizenship if she took Canadian citizenship.

On the one hand, how would Brazil ever find out?  On the other hand, she could just retire to Canada as a permanent resident (but this would mean she couldn't vote in Canada).

Naturalizing as a Canadian would have no affect on her US citizenship.

Comment: Of course, she could retire to Canada as a permanent resident and retain her Brazilian citizenship without having to deceive Brazil.

Comment: It might also be worth mentioning that she can retain her US citizenship if she naturalizes in Canada.

Comment: Thank you very much. I appreciate your prompt responses.. :)